# Creating a new widget on User Click(Flat Button)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Post class that creates a Post model. And I want to create this model every time a user clicks the flat button. What's the best way to go about this using the onPressed function?

It's going to be a post that holds the text the user adds to the text field and when they submit it will show on a new post.

Comment: Use the `onPressed` property of the button to do something in response to the button being pressed.

Comment: Show us what you have so far. Then we can help in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

u can try use listview.builder, this the simple example how to use it. i just edit default code when we created new project.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(

    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(

    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _counter,
      reverse: true,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(child: Text('data $index')),
          ),
        );
      },

    )
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ), 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to add items to a list, and then render the contents of that list.

```
List<String> messages = [];
...
onPressed: ()=> setState(()=>messages.add("SomeText"))
```

Then render the list:

```
//Can use the map() api, to convert the list of Strings into a list of widgets:
List<Widget> children = messages.map((m) => Text(m));
return ListView(children: children);

//Or, use ListView.builder() to create the widgets on demand:
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index)=>Text(messages[index]),
  itemCount: messages.length
)
```

The builder method is better optimized for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple demo

```
List<String> posts = [];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(body: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: posts.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                         return new Text(posts[index]);//use any widget
                   }
                ),
               FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                 setState(() {
                   posts.add(newpost);//add what you want
                   });
                },
              ),
             ]),
          );
    }
```

i hope it helps..